# Shortcuts not showing up on other domain users in Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a windows server 2008 r2 edition. I go to group policy management and then edit a gpo and set the shortcut in the User configuration . I then run `gpupdate /force` but the shortcut still does not show up on my users computers.(The gpo is linked and enabled and enforced.) The shortcut shows on the server but not on the users computers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting this through the group policy preferences? what OS are the user computers? XP computers will require the GPP [Client extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628) to be installed in order to pick up the group policy preferences.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot. Just out of curiosity- How did you find this?

Comment: find it? Its something that I've just known for a while having done a bit with group policy preferences over the years..